# Starting Blackfin (BF527)

Tags: c, port, sample, gpio, blackfin

I am very new in Blackfin processors and I suppose to write a tester program for Blackfin, BF527. This tester program should test the connection of the board and 2 peripheral RAMs.

So far I have downloaded and installed VisualDSP++ (90-day trial version).

Can anyone help me to know how can I write a simple program to write in port G and read From port H, including initialization (preferably in C).

I have looked for sample code on internet but unfortunately all the codes are very advance.

I went through the data sheet, but it was on assembly not C, still I couldn't find any solid sample program for my purpose.

Comment: I don't know what runtime support libraries are supplied by your compiler, but generally speaking getting a board up and running from scratch *is* an advanced topic, which probably is why you're not finding any simple code. Read the manuals and documentation, while looking at what example code you can find.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the VisualDSP installation folder (under Program Files). There is lots of sample C and C++ code in `Analog Devices\VisualDSP 5.0\Blackfin\Examples`

To program the hardware peripherals from C/C++ you need the header files which contain the pointer definitions for the memory-mapped registers. These will be found in `Analog Devices\VisualDSP 5.0\Blackfin\include`
In your code you can automatically select the correct include file for the project's processor using:

```
#include <blackfin.h>
```